# Auto complete textbox for php from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, mongodb

Here is my code

autocomplete.php

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript"
    src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>



     <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#name").autocomplete({
                    source:'test.php',
                    minLength:1,
                    selectFirst: true
                });
            });
      </script>
      </head>

     <body>

       <form method="post" action="">
         Name : <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
      </form>

     </body>
     <html>
```

test.php

```
  <?php
   $my_string =$_GET['q'];
   //echo $my_string;
   syslog($priority, $my_string);
    try {

    // Connect to MongoDB
    $conn = new Mongo('localhost');

    // connect to test database
    $db = $conn->mydb;

    // a new products collection object
    $collection = $db->QuoteCollections;

$quote_array = array(
                    'Author' => $my_string,
                    );        

       $cursor = $collection->find($quote_array);
       //$json=$cursor;

   foreach ($cursor as $obj)
    {
         //$json[]=array(
                //'value'=> $student["Author"],
                //'label'=>$student["Author"]
                   // );
    echo 'Name: ' . $obj['Author'] . "\r\n<br>";
    echo $row['Author']."\n";
    }

      //echo json_encode($json);




        // close connection to MongoDB
         $conn->close();

  }
  catch ( MongoConnectionException $e )
  {
    // if there was an error, we catch and display the problem here
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "error at mongoconexe";
  }
 catch ( MongoException $e )
 {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "error at mongoconeException";
  }

?>
```

i cannot get the result, i referd these links

http://phpseason.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/php-autocomplete-tutorial-using-jquery/

http://tutsforweb.blogspot.in/2012/05/auto-complete-text-box-with-php-jquery.html

i placed both js files inside a js folder

please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i figured it out,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AutoComplete for Mongo with php</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    try {
    // Connect to MongoDB
    $conn = new Mongo('localhost');

    // connect to test database
    $db = $conn->mydb;

    // a new products collection object
    $collection = $db->QuoteCollections;

// the array of product criteria
    $query = $collection->find(array(),array("Author"=>1)); ?>
    <label for="brgy">select:</label>
    <input type="text" list="datlist" autocomplete="off" id="brgy">
    <datalist id ="datlist">
<?php        foreach($query as $result) 
        {  
            //echo $result['Author'];  ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $result['Author']; ?>"></option>

        <?php
        }  ?>
      </datalist>

      <?php



    // close connection to MongoDB
    $conn->close();

   }
     catch ( MongoConnectionException $e )
     {
    // if there was an error, we catch and display the problem here
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "error at mongoconexe";
}
 catch ( MongoException $e )
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "error at mongoconeException";
}
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

worked fine for me in firefox